# Responsive design broken when redirecting via php

Tags: php, redirect, responsive-design

I have a page with a survey, which when accessed from http://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/3424900/Test-survey-March-2017 looks fine on mobile devices. I have then tried to make a redirect with the following php code on our  at [own domain](http://mbla.dk/test):

```
<?php 
    header("Location: http://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/3424900/Test-survey-March-2017");
    die();
?>
```

Now however the responsive design doesn't look good (although it is adapted to mobile version).

I have run two tests, which confirms this.

Test redirect: https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly?id=J4mlYOr8M-5JtfiIvRklLQ

Test default: https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly?id=_siROcWpr4cz7TOmsWuYPw

Comment: The page at http://mbla.dk/test is using framesets. That's a relic of 1990's web design and goes completely against the principles of responsive design. Furthermore, in your PHP fragment above you issue a header and then send a `die()` statement, which will interfere with your output. You're better off using `exit();`. Finally, that PHP is not compatible with what I'm actually seeing when I visit the link. Are you sure the http://mbla.dk/test link is correct?

Comment: Ah, apologies, yes, indeed did some further experimenting and changed the link - it should now be identical to the one written above. Will try using `exit();` instead...

Comment: I still see framesets :-(

Comment: Hm, guess I have to figure out how to avoid that. As it is now I have simply put it in the editor that our domain host provides. Any suggestions on where to find information on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to work around your provider's `frameset`, I think you'll have to use javascript to work around it. It's not as clean as a true redirect, I'm afraid.

Replace the php script at redirect page with this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            parent.location.href="http://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/3424900/Test-survey-March-2017";
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `die()` statement will interfere with your output. Try the following instead:

```
<?php 
    header("Location: http://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/3424900/Test-survey-March-2017");
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately to no avail. Ran the test again: https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly?id=pzBlU9B-VasqMXmWOu-7gw